# Handle extra elements outside of deserialized class

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Putting extra elements property in the class to support backward/forward compatibility and implement ISupportInitialize seems ugly for me and it is also OCP violation.
I want to handle extra elements outside of deserialized class and run some migration logic in external classes.
I mean that Bson serializer will put extra elements data somewhere not on the deserialized class and than after finishing all deserialization staff call some migrator for loaded object. 
That way I can can support compatibility between fetched document (that may be in older or newest version) and currently running code.

Something like:

```
public interface IMigrate<T>
{
    void Migrate(T obj, BsonDocument extraElements)
}

public class MigrateClazzA : IMigrate<ClazzA>
{
    public void Migrate(ClazzA obj, BsonDocument extraElements)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

How can I do it?